# Pipe output of multiple programs to netcat on same port

Tags: node.js, pipe, netcat

So right now I have a server that is pinging an api and writes to stdout. I pipe that to nc as such.

```
node server.js | nc -lk 9999
```

I then have a job that listens to that and outputs 5 second snapshots of the data.

My question is that when I try to do that in multiple sessions with multiple server.js programs eg. server1.js, server2.js which all hit different parts of the api and pipe them all to port 9999. Only the first program gets picked up by the snapshot job. How do I pipe multiple outputs to:

```
nc -lk 9999
```

such that they all get handled as if it's the output of one program?

Comment: I think you'll find that the `-lk` options tell `nc` to listen on a port, which implies 'ignore standard input'.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute multiple times that command, it simply won't work. You cannot listen with several instances of netcat on the same port. You should get a `nc: Address already in use` error.

What you can do is something like:

1. `mkfifo queue`
2. `nc -lk 9999 < queue`
3. `node server.js | cat > queue`

Btw I did a nice and fully working Netcat porting in Node.js: https://github.com/roccomuso/netcat

This easily address the issue you're encountering, because you can implement the whole logic in JS without using the native `nc` bin or pipe data on the stdin.